# Is there a ssh nuget package for .net-core 3?

Tags: .net-core, ssh

Im in need of a new ssh (and sftp) package for dotnet core 3.0. I used SSH.NET but that failed to work since a week or 2.

Im not able to find a suitable replacement searching a package (with actual examples) using the nuget package search.

Answer (score 0):

using Renci.SshNet again. problem was a strange character in password pasing.